# How to change a global parameter inside a decorator and automatically reset it?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to change a config dictionary inside the decorator (So I don't have to mess with the code of the function `do_something()` itself). I am experiencing problems however with 'resetting' the dictionary to its old state.

How do I do this? And is there a better way going forward than this approach (without changing the `do_something()` code itself)?

I've tried several approaches in regards to placement of the CONFIG variable, but in the end, the global context is never reset to the original state.

```py
import copy

CONFIG = {
    'key': 'value'
}


def alter_dictionary_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        old = copy.deepcopy(CONFIG)
        CONFIG['key'] = 'other_value'
        func = function()
        config = old # <- can't put 'CONFIG = old' here
        return func
    return wrapper

@alter_dictionary_decorator
def do_something():
    print(CONFIG['key'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(CONFIG['key'])
    do_something()
    print(CONFIG['key'])
```

Expected results = 'value', 'other_value', 'value'

Observerd results = 'value', 'other_value', 'other_value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `global` keyword in order to modify variables that have global scope. Also, `config = old` should have been `CONFIG = old`.

The following code works as you require:

```
import copy

CONFIG = {
    'key': 'value'
}


def alter_dictionary_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        global CONFIG
        old = copy.deepcopy(CONFIG)
        CONFIG['key'] = 'other_value'
        func = function()
        CONFIG = old
        return func
    return wrapper

@alter_dictionary_decorator
def do_something():
    print(CONFIG['key'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(CONFIG['key'])
    do_something()
    print(CONFIG['key'])
```

With the output being:

```
value
other_value
value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did indeed fix it. And you were correct, one line of code in my example was wrong, but this was intentional because the code produced errors. I added this to the original post just before you replied :)

Comment: Yes, that `UnboundLocalError` is caused because it doesn't want you to modify global variables in a local scope, and the solution is using the `global` keyword.